# Writing values from excel cells to notepad using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to copy certain calculated values from MS excel to notepad. But its fetching empty values. can someone please check and help me resolve this issue?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

  workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(filereader & "excelfilename.xls")
  worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

  Dim Datawriter As New StreamWriter(filereader & "FiletoCopy.txt")


  Dim range1 As Excel.Range
  Dim range2 As Excel.Range
  Dim range3 As Excel.Range
  Dim range4 As Excel.Range
  Dim range5 As Excel.Range



  Dim CellValue1 As String
  Dim CellValue2 As String
  Dim CellValue3 As String
  Dim CellValue4 As String
  Dim CellValue5 As String



   range1 = CType(worksheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range(“A1”)
   range2 = CType(worksheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range(“A2”)
   range3 = CType(worksheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range(“A3”)
   range4 = CType(worksheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range(“A4”)
   range5 = CType(worksheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range(“A5”)



   CellValue1 = Math.Round((range1.Value), 2)
   CellValue2 = Math.Round((range2.Value), 2)
   CellValue3 = Math.Round((range3.Value), 2)
   CellValue4 = Math.Round((range4.Value), 2)
   CellValue5 = Math.Round((range5.Value), 2)

   Datawriter.WriteLine(CellValue1, vbCrLf)
   Datawriter.WriteLine(CellValue2, vbCrLf)
   Datawriter.WriteLine(CellValue3, vbCrLf)
   Datawriter.WriteLine(CellValue4, vbCrLf)
   Datawriter.WriteLine(CellValue5, vbCrLf)


   Datawriter.Close()

   MessageBox.Show("Output Generated Sucessfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub
```

Comment: I would check that `filereader` value is a string containing a valid path and ending with the slash `\\`

Comment: @Ahmad Hi! I tried that but the path exists and also ends with "\" , But still the values aren't getting copied.

Comment: In this case, add a break point before writing to the file and debug the code and make sure that the worksheet you are reading from already contains the data that you expect to find

Comment: Have you checked via debugging that range1..range5 are actually getting a value?  Perhaps the Datawriter part is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I changed the names of your worksheet and workbook. I just don't like variables named the same as the class name.

I used `Path.Combine` so I don't have to worry about whether the backslash is there or not.

I created and filled a list of doubles containing the values from you spreadsheet.

I am using a string builder to build the text to be saved. A `StringBuilder` is mutable (changeable) unlike a String. Each string would have to be discarded and a new one created otherwise.

I used the `File` class in `System.IO` to create and write the file.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim filereader = "C:\SomeFolder\"
    Dim wbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(filereader, "excelfilename.xls"))
    Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wbook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim lstDoubles As New List(Of Double) From {
        CDbl(wsheet.Range("A1").Value),
        CDbl(wsheet.Range("A2").Value),
        CDbl(wsheet.Range("A3").Value),
        CDbl(wsheet.Range("A4").Value),
        CDbl(wsheet.Range("A5").Value)
    }
    'StringBuilder requires Imports System.Text
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each d In lstDoubles
        Dim roundedString = Math.Round(d, 2).ToString
        sb.AppendLine(roundedString)
    Next
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(filereader, "FiletoCopy.txt"), sb.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("Output Generated Sucessfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following methods. I just slightly modified some of your code.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Dim filereader As String = "E:\Julie\Case\AccessDB\"
    Dim xls As Application = New Application()
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(filereader & "exceltest.xlsx")
        Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim Datawriter As New StreamWriter(filereader & "FiletoCopy.txt")
        For i = 1 To 5
            Dim temp As String = (CType(Worksheet.Cells(1, i), Range)).Text
            Datawriter.WriteLine(temp, vbCrLf)
        Next
        Datawriter.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Output Generated Sucessfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Sub
End Class
```